Trivial but Confusing question on basic probability
Suppose we have a deck of 52 cards. I would like to find the probability that the second card is an Ace.
There are two ways to approach this problem. The first one is if we randomly select the second card first before the other cards, then we just need to count the number of Aces in a deck (4) divided by the number of cards in a deck (52) and hence we get $\frac{4}{52}$.
Another way is if say we pick the first card first before the second, where we can use Bayes formula. let $A$ denote the event that the second card is an ace and $B$ denote the event that the first card is an ace.
$$P(A) = P(A|B)P(B) + P(A|B')P(B')$$
Then,
$$P(A) = \frac{4}{52} \times \frac{3}{51} + \frac{48}{52} \times \frac{4}{51}$$
$$P(A) = \frac{4}{52}$$
Just out of curiosity, why is the order of which we pick the cards randomly doesn't change the probability of a certain card being an Ace? It may seem a trivial but is there a more algebraic reasoning behind this? I still can't wrap my head around why can this happen.

You have already worked out the algebra by dividing it into two disjoint cases. What maybe you are asking is the intuition  for why P(first card is an ace) = P(second card is an ace). That intuition is that an ace (or any card) has no preference for position, so a priori, a particular card is equally likely to be at any position

Here is one way to think about it:
Define event $J$ as choosing an Ace and then choosing a second card.
And event $K$ as choosing a card and then choosing an Ace.
By symmetry, you would expect $Pr(J)=Pr(K)$.
Now, in event $J$, the second card is largely irrelevant, so $Pr(J)=\frac{4}{52}=\frac{1}{13}$.
Therefore, $Pr(K)=\frac{1}{13}$ also.
